# Auto resize a dialog control when parent window is resized WinApi

Tags: windows, winapi, resources, dialog, autoresize

I am trying to show a web page in a dialog control. All is working fine till I maximize the parent window, the inner control with webpage retains its size and so a blank area is left at the side of window. I want to know is there any WS_* message or something I can use to auto resize control when we resize the main window. I am using resource hacker so may be there can be some trick I should know.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The application must perform the resize. And it does so when it receives a [`WM_SIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms632646.aspx) message for the parent control.

You are not going to be able change this by modifying the resources in a pre-existing binary. You are going to need to write some code to respond to that message.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd try seeing as I've never tried to hack something like this in.
Would be to see if the web control had an anchors property.
Its should be being passed a wm-size message, it's just not doing anything with it.
If you anchor all four corners of the webcontrol it should resize relative to it's parent.
The other way this is done is through explicit code that handles a resize event, don't think you could hack that in very easily though.

Comment: Windows doesn't have the concept of anchors

Comment: The inner control he's using might, he shrugs.

Comment: one assumes it's a dialog resource rather than a VCL .dfm file

Comment: Not where I was going. I was thinking hack in a control with an anchors property. No idea whether you can or not. I missed out on all the fun creating rc files and such, those were my vms days.

Comment: There are no anchors properties. That's what I said first of all.